# Twitter Boostrap bugs in Buttons just in firefox and IE?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, button

I have some unusual behaviour on my portfolio website in firefox. I am using twitter bootstrap.The text on buttons is going beyond the button width, also nothing happens on clicking the buttons. It works fine on chrome and safari.

Link: www.nakibmomin.com

**html**

```
 <div class="parallax-overlay"></div>
    <div class="jumbotron" id="home">
      <div class="container">
        <img class="img-circle" src="img/profile.jpg" style="width: 100px;height:100px;">
        <h1>Nakib Momin</h1>
        <p>Student Blogger And Software Developer</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><a href="#contact">Contact Me</a></button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**css**

```
.parallax-overlay {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 120;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-image: url(../img/pattern.png);
background-repeat: repeat;
background-color: rgba(44,62,80,0.4);
z-index: 2;
min-height: 460px;
}

.jumbotron {

  background-image:url('../img/main.jpg');
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Hammersmith One', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 460px;
}

.jumbotron .container {
  position: relative;
  top:120px;
}

.jumbotron h1, .jumbotron p, .jumbotron a, .jumbotron button, .jumbotron img
{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}

.jumbotron img
{
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 2px;
}

.jumbotron button
{
  margin-top: 18px; 
  width: 130px;
}

.jumbotron h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 48px;  
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;

}

.jumbotron p {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #e3e3e3;

}

.jumbotron a {
  font-size: 15px;
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to provide the relevant code in your question, as well as what you've done to try and fix it. Simply linking to your site isn't enough. The code may change at some point in the future, or the site could go offline, rendering this question useless to future users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't put anchor tags inside of button tags.

Either make it an actual button and redirect users to your contact me page when they click it, or style the button using Bootstrap's button classes.

[**BOOTPLY**](http://www.bootply.com/VdnmCIfko9)

**HTML**:

```
<a href="#contact" class="btn btn-primary">Contact Me</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't put `<a>`s inside `<button>`s. They don't work properly and it's very unclear what proper behavior for such a combination would even be.

Comment: oh thanks...but y doing so remove any padding from contact button?